# Jquery - Select empty text input and add border for them

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to add a border for empty text input fields. So I wrote a following code. But it is not working. So i used alert box for get to know how many selectors are select. But it is return 0. What is my wrong?

```
 $("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
       var empty = $('input:text[value=""]');
       alert(empty.length);

       if(empty.length >0){

           $("form").effect("shake",{
               times:3,
               distance : 50         

           },450,function(){
           $('input:text[value=""]').each(function(){
              $(this).css("border","1px solid red"); 
           });
           });



           return false;
       }

   });
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: If you have form tags I strongly suggest you do `$("#formId").on("submit",function(e){` instead and do an `e.preventDefault()` if the validation fails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `.filter()` for this purpose, value attribute won't get affected while you changing the value in it.

```
$('input:text').filter(function(){
   return $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
}).css("border","1px solid red");
```

Comment: @gym25 And your happiness made me happy.. :) Glad to help.!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    var isShake = 0;
    $('input:text').filter(function(){
        if ($.trim(this.value).length == 0){
            isShake = 1;
            $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
        }else{
            $(this).css("border","1px solid black");
        }           
    });

    if(isShake){
        alert('Shake Effect or something like');
    }
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5sk4vxL5/2/)**